# Superforms overwrites form elements on update

Tags: sveltekit-superforms

I'm creating an AI chat application using SvelteKit and Superforms.

The application has an input field for writing a message. When pressing enter, the input field is cleared, and two messages are entered into the conversation: the user's message and a placeholder message "..." that will be replaced by the AI's response when it is ready. While waiting for a response from the AI, the user can start writing another message. But when the form action returns, Superform overwrites whatever the user has entered into the input field while waiting. I think the reason is that the input field uses `bind:value={$form.message}`, and `$form.message` is updated when the form action returns.

How can I avoid overwriting the input field?

I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltekit-superforms-1-testing-6mkmdt?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte) showing the issue. To try it, write a message, press enter, and start writing another message without waiting for the AI's response to be ready.

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  import { superForm } from 'sveltekit-superforms/client';

  export let data;

  const { form, enhance } = superForm(data.form, {
    onSubmit: () => {
      data.messages = [
        ...data.messages,
        $form.message,
        "..."
      ]
      // This lines clears the input box on submit.
      $form.message = "";
    }
  });
</script>

<ul>
  {#each data.messages as message}
    <li>{message}</li>
  {/each}
</ul>

<form method="POST" use:enhance>
  <input
    name="message"
    autofocus
    bind:value={$form.message}
    placeholder="Send message"
  />
</form>
```

```js
// +page.server.ts
import { superValidate } from 'sveltekit-superforms/server';
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { z } from 'zod';
import type { Actions, PageServerLoad } from './$types';

const messages: string[] = [];

const schema = z.object({
  message: z.string().trim().min(1)
});

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
  const form = await superValidate(schema);
  return {
    form,
    messages
  };
};

export const actions: Actions = {
  default: async ({ request }) => {
    const form = await superValidate(request, schema);

    if (!form.valid) return fail(400, { form });

    messages.push(form.data.message);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    messages.push('This is a response');

    // This line prevents populating the input field with the message just sent,
    // but it will overwrite any message the user has written in the meantime.
    form.data.message = "";

    return {
      form,
      messages
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to `bind` the input value to another variable `message`, and then use a reactive declaration to update `$form.message` whenever `message` changes. Clearing `form.data.message` in `+page.server.ts` is no longer necessary.

Here is an updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltekit-superforms-1-testing-qqd6gy?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte)

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  // ...

  const { form, enhance } = superForm(data.form, {
    onSubmit: () => {
      data.messages = [
        ...data.messages,
        message,
        "..."
      ]
      // Clear the input box on submit.
      message = "";
    }
  });

  // Prevent Superform from overwriting the form element value on form action return.
  let message = $form.message;
  $: $form.message = message;
</script>

<!-- ... -->

<form method="POST" use:enhance>
  <input
    name="message"
    autofocus
    bind:value={message}
    placeholder="Send message"
  />
</form>
```